# Is it possible to use a single jQuery mobile widget within a non-mobile web page?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery UI to put some widgets on a web page primarily designed for large screens.
I was looking for a [flipswitch](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/flipswitch/) widget, and I found one provided by jQuery mobile framework.

Is it possible to use jQuery mobile to just make this flipswitch widget work, without the whole jQuery mobile theming ?

Comment: yes it is possible. Create a [custom build](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/).

Comment: Thanks Omar for your answer. Could you please put this into an answer instead of a comment so that I can accept it ? Also, another question : How do I activate the widget on my page ? Is there a jQuery method to call, like for jQuery UI widgets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery Mobile's widgets by creating a [custom build](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/). All you have to do is to choose the widgets you want, and then load JS library as well as style sheets in head. You will also need to *modify* style sheets, either by modifying them manually or using [ThemeRoller](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/).

HTML

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="structure.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css" />
  <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="custom-build.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <label for="flip-checkbox-1">Flip toggle switch checkbox:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-1" id="flip-checkbox-1">
  </form>
</body>
```

To initialize the widget, just call `.flipswitch()` on `.ready()`. For more methods, check widget's [API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/flipswitch/).

```
$(function () {
  $("#flip-checkbox-1").flipswitch();
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5r70dxub/)**

Comment: That the type of answers I like : complete, simple, straightforward. Thanks a lot ! By the way, I did not find anywhere in the documentation that you can call the `flipswitch` method to initialize the widget instead of relying exclusively on the markup. Is it only due to [the use of jQuery UI widget factory in jQuery mobile version 1.4](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/widgets/) ?

Comment: @FabienQuatravaux you're welcome :) inside the widget, you can add `initSelector: "[data-role=flipswitch]";` but I'm not sure if it will work. Since it's a widget, it doesn't init itself, unlike JQM framework, it initializes all widget within the framework. I'll test initSelector and let you know. Maybe you would need to add _init_ when you create the custom build.

Comment: @FabienQuatravaux `initSelector` doesn't work, so you'll need to initialize it manually.

Comment: @FabienQuatravaux theme style sheet should loaded before structure.