# jQuery Mobile Reflow Table Headers Disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have tried adding a jQuery reflow table to my website but when it goes to mobile the top row table headers disappear when they should appear beside the `<td>` content.

[Top row TH not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvFBG.png)

I can't use jsfiddle as it uses the cdn for jQuery Mobile which seems to work fully but I can't use the CDN as it breaks the site.
Web Page:
[Test Web Page](http://www.relationships.co.uk/test-3/)

The HTML:

```
<table data-role="table" id="result" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-responsive ui-table ui-table-reflow table-stroke">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Movie Title</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th><abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Rating</abbr></th>
      <th>Reviews</th>
      <th>Director</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane" data-rel="external">Citizen Kane</a></td>
      <td>1941</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>74</td>
      <td>Orson Welles</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca_(film)" data-rel="external">Casablanca</a></td>
      <td>1942</td>
      <td>97%</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>Michael Curtiz</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I downloaded the custom build for jQuery reflow from the website, so maybe it is missing some modules? It works using the full download or CDN.

Comment: Can you provide a full working code sample please?

Comment: Specifically, can you share any CSS you're using?

Comment: I can't use jsfiddle as it uses the cdn for jQuery Mobile which seems to work fully but I can't use the CDN as it breaks the site.
Web Page:
http://www.relationships.co.uk/test-3/

Comment: When using a custom build - which isn't recommended - you have to initialize widgets manually `$("your-table").table()` on `.ready()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the key is to add the Core Init package when creating your customized build. Here are the options I had to select (which will auto-select some other dependencies) when building the customized build:

- Core

  - Init
- Widgets

  - Table: reflow

As mentioned, selecting these will select a bunch of other required packages. But the result will be the table works as expected on smaller screens, with the table headers placed next to the table rows.

Comment: Yes this now works, thanks. The only other issue is that it breaks navigation now on the website, is there a way to disable this?

Comment: You probably need to add the necessary Navigation packages to the custom build. I was only selecting the bare minimum packages to get the reflow table working. Maybe the Navbar Widget package. Hard to say without seeing what you had before.

Comment: Putting this in seems to work:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>

Comment: @MartinMulholland Just select the widget you want and then initialize it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27542898/1771795